# ¿Cómo ajustar de manera correcta las vidas en un quiz?

Tags: ciclos, while

Hice un pequeño programa en donde te pide que adivines un número y no termina hasta que lo adivines, luego lo decidí hacer con vidas.

Cuando las vidas terminan a 0, el programa no termina y sigue su ciclo haciendo que aparezca *"Te quedan -1 vidas"* y así. Alguna ayuda?

```
public class Main5 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int N, num;
    int contador = 5;

    N = (int)(Math.random()*10)+1;

    System.out.println("Introduzca el número a adivinar entre el 0 y el 10:");
    num = Entrada.entero();

    while (contador < 1 || num != N) 
    {

        if (num > N) {
                System.out.println("MAYOR");
        }else {
                System.out.println("MENOR");
        }
            contador --;
            System.out.println("Te quedan " +contador+ " vida/s, introduce otro número:");
            num = Entrada.entero();

    }

    System.out.println("ACERTASTE!");

}
```

}

**No logro encontrar el error, soy novato :(, de antemano gracias.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error está en la comparación del `while` ya que sería haga mientras **contador** sea menor a **1** o **num** distinto de **N**

Una solución que no modifique mucho tu código sería, utilizar solo el **contador** en el ciclo `while` y dentro del ciclo comparar **N** con el número que ingrese el usuario **num**. Entonces quedaría así:

```
public class Main5 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int N, num;
    int contador = 5;

    N = (int)(Math.random()*10)+1;

    System.out.println("Introduzca el número a adivinar entre el 0 y el 10:");
    num = Entrada.entero();

    while (contador > 0) {

        if (num == N) {
            //Si al entrar al ciclo num coincide con N, entonces se  
            //imprime que acertó y con el 'break;' culmina el ciclo.
            System.out.println("ACERTASTE!");
            break;
        } else if(num > N) {
            System.out.println("MAYOR");
        } else {
            System.out.println("MENOR");
        }
        //En otros casos se imprime si es Mayor o Menor, disminuye el contador y además
        //se solicita un nuevo número.
        contador --;
        if (contador > 0) {
            System.out.println("Te quedan " +contador+ " vida(s), introduce otro número:");
            num = Entrada.entero();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Te has quedado sin vidas. Juego terminado");
        }

    }
  }
}
```

---

Aquí esta un ejemplo corriendo en Rextester (se simula el ingreso de **num**)
[Ejemplo adivinando un número, Java Rextester](http://rextester.com/BZD48912)

Comment: Me sirvió hermano, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

La condición del contador debe ser `contador > 0` así cuando llege a cero saldrá del bucle (while), pero deberias verificar si el contador es mayor que cero al salir del while porque en caso de que salga porque se le terminó las vidas imprimiria el mensaje "ACERTASTE" cuando no es cierto.

Comment: Ya intenté y sale igual

Answer (score 0):

tu problema esta en que tienes una condición || eso quiere decir q aun cuando el contador ya se haya cumplido si no cumples la otra condición el ciclo no va a terminar nunca, intenta cambiando la condición asi:

```
while (contador > 0 || num != N)
```

he incrementa el siguiente if dentro del while asi cumplirás con ambas condiciones al terminar el contador

```
if(contador <= 0) { 
num = N;
}
```

otra opción tamb seria cambiar la logica para que el while solo quede asi:

while (contador > 0 )

y luego interno al while realizar un break al ciclo cuando la persona adivine el numero, eso seria algo como esto:

```
  while (contador > 0) 
        {

     if (num == N){
        break;
    }else {
            if (num > N) {
                    System.out.println("MAYOR");
            }else {
                    System.out.println("MENOR");
            }
                contador --;
                System.out.println("Te quedan " +contador+ " vida/s, introduce otro número:");
                num = Entrada.entero();

        }

 }
```